# Fully expand an argument of a newenvironment created with expl3

Tags: environments, expl3, expansion

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/696341/17200) answer, I was provided with the following code that solves my original problem.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{withalignment}{m}
 {
  \begin{\vincent_alignment:n { #1 }}
 }
 {
  \end{\vincent_alignment:n { #1 }}
 }

\cs_new:Nn \vincent_alignment:n
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {c}{center}
    {center}{center}
    {l}{flushleft}
    {left}{flushleft}
    {r}{flushright}
    {right}{flushright}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

that can be used this way:

```
\begin{withalignment}{left}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{withalignment}

\begin{withalignment}{center}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{withalignment}
```

The problem, however is when I provide the alignment through a macro/command:

```
\newcommand{\myalignment}{center}
\begin{withalignment}{\myalignment}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{withalignment}
```

It does not seem to work. How to fully expand the argument before processing it so that it works?

Comment: `\str_case:en`, or generate a e-variant for `\vincent_alignment:n`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Could you provide code, expl3 being an alien language to me?

Comment: In your code, just exchange `str_case:nn` with `str_case:en`.

Comment: Oh, @muzimuzhiZ was faster :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes I made:

- [required] In defining `\vincent_alignment:n`, `\str_case:nn` is replaced with `\str_case:en`
- [optional] In defining `withalignment` environment, an `\exp_args:Ne` is added in front of `\begin` and `\end` respectively. This change is optional, but should make `withalignment` more efficient.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{withalignment}{m}
 {
  \exp_args:Ne \begin {\vincent_alignment:n { #1 }}
 }
 {
  \exp_args:Ne \end {\vincent_alignment:n { #1 }}
 }

\cs_new:Nn \vincent_alignment:n
 {
  \str_case:en { #1 }
   {
    {c}{center}
    {center}{center}
    {l}{flushleft}
    {left}{flushleft}
    {r}{flushright}
    {right}{flushright}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{withalignment}{left}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{withalignment}

\begin{withalignment}{center}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{withalignment}

\newcommand{\myalignment}{center}
\begin{withalignment}{\myalignment}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{withalignment}

\renewcommand{\myalignment}{right}
\begin{withalignment}{\myalignment}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{withalignment}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Bonus: Applying the second solution [Ulrike Fischer suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/696423/fully-expand-an-argument-of-a-newenvironment-created-with-expl3#comment1729265_696423) in question comment

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{withalignment}{m}
 {
  \exp_args:Ne \begin {\vincent_alignment:e { #1 }}
 }
 {
  \exp_args:Ne \end {\vincent_alignment:e { #1 }}
 }

\cs_new:Nn \vincent_alignment:n
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {c}{center}
    {center}{center}
    {l}{flushleft}
    {left}{flushleft}
    {r}{flushright}
    {right}{flushright}
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \vincent_alignment:n {e}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{withalignment}{left}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{withalignment}

\begin{withalignment}{center}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{withalignment}

\newcommand{\myalignment}{center}
\begin{withalignment}{\myalignment}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{withalignment}

\renewcommand{\myalignment}{right}
\begin{withalignment}{\myalignment}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{withalignment}
\end{document}
```